# Is there a specific iOS device size that is standard to use when building out the first version of an app?

Tags: ios

Does it matter which UI size you build first? I know most people recommend building out the iPhone version of the app first - but does it matter which iPhone version (i.e. iPhone XR, iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus)?

Maybe simply going off of the most used device, and build from there?

Comment: You need to support all iPhone screen sizes initially so your question doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: It's all using Auto Layout, so it's all kind of the same thing.  That said most designers seem to use the iPhone 8 as the standard size.  You'll still want to make sure the design looks decent on smaller devices like the iPhone SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really need to focus on is testing your app on all sizes. It doesn't really matter which iPhone size you start with, you should make sure that the UI follows AutoLayout and it's compatible with iPhone SE, 8, X and etc.